# What font size is used in the 'thebibliography' environment?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I'm preparing an application for the NSF GRFP and I'm checking to make sure my research plan conforms to their standards. Looking it over, it looks like LaTeX's `thebibliography` environment uses a slightly smaller font in the references section.  I have the document set to 12 point font, but the references section has a font that looks distinctly smaller.  Is this the way `thebibliography` is supposed to work?  How can I find out how small the font is?  (I'm using `amsart` if that helps.)

Answer (score 9):

since you're using `amsart`, you can adjust the size of the font in the bibliography with a single command:

```
\renewcommand{\bibliofont}{<desired font size>}
```

the default setting is  `\newcommand{\bibliofont}{\footnotesize}`.  if you want the same size type as the main text, then `\normalsize` is what you should specify.

Answer (score 7):

The `amsart` document class provides the instruction

```
\newcommand{\bibliofont}{\footnotesize}
```

and sets up the `thebibliography` environment as follows:

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
   ...
   \bibliofont % switch to footnote-size text
   ...
```

The `amsart` also provides the instruction

```
\def\footnotesize{\Small}
```

Finally, if the main document font size is `12pt`, `\Small` works out to be `10pt`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this command in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\printfontsize{Fontsize=\f@size}
\makeatother
```

And then in a item of your bibliography or where else you want to find the size use the command temporary. You can make it red to find easier like:

```
\makeatletter
\def\printfontsize{{\color{red}Fontsize=\f@size}}
\makeatother
```

Then at the printed bibliography you will see the font size of every place used the `\printfontsize` command because may be someone have changed font size of title or author etc